# How do I use this CI CD Extenstion called SCC for GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I found this quick and easy utility for counting lines of code and detecting technologies called [SCC (Sloc Cloc and Code)](https://github.com/boyter/scc).  I would like to incorporate it into my GitLab CI/CD Pipeline, ideally outputting a file into my repository that is updated during each Test stage.

I also found this [Extension for GitLab](https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/code-metrics/ci-cd-extension-scc) that I think will help, although I don't know how to best use it. I think that I should merge the content from their **requirements.txt** & **.gitlab-ci.yml** file into mine (shown below) & include their other files (**ci-cd-extension.scc.yml** & **list-groups.py**) into my project?

I feel like there's probably a better way that I don't know about.

My **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
image: python:3.10

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  POSTGRES_DB: django_aws
  DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/django_aws
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  AWS_REGISTRY_URL: "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:latest"


test:
  services:
    - postgres:14.2
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - requirements.txt
      prefix: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
    paths:
      - venv
      - .cache/pip
  stage: test
  script:
    - python -m venv venv
    - . venv/bin/activate
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python manage.py test

build:
  stage: build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  services:
    - docker:20.10-dind
  before_script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_REGISTRY_URL
  script:
    - docker pull $AWS_REGISTRY_URL || true
    - docker build --cache-from $AWS_REGISTRY_URL -t $AWS_REGISTRY_URL .
    - docker push $AWS_REGISTRY_URL
  only:
    - main

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - chmod +x ./scripts/deploy.sh
    - ./scripts/deploy.sh
  only:
    - main
```

My **requirements.txt** file:

```
Django==3.2.13
django-environ==0.8.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
whitenoise==6.1.0
celery[sqs]==5.2.6
boto3==1.24.45
django_storages==1.13.1
pillow==9.1.0
```